# Эффект прокрутки в slick slider

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

Доброе утро , мне надо добиться такого эффекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть инструкция по такому эффекту или надо использовать другой слайдер ?

спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Во первых**, Такой эффект, это какой?

**Во вторых**, у них(или не у них) есть на мой взгляд, достаточно хорошая [Документация](https://realadmin.ru/saytostroy/slick-slider.html).
Там подробно описывается создание слайдеров.

**В третьих**, по [ссылке](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), есть такой же пример, только вместо экрана телефона, обычная кнопка, но суть идентична вашей (7й слайдер, название - Center Mode)

Comment: center mode не поможет , слайд должен всплывать из зади активного , и как видно на макете третий слайд находится ниже второго

Comment: Ну, код можно менять, поменять стили под себя. Функционал то такой же

Comment: ну я не понимаю что нужно менять вообще , может есть демо ?

Comment: Нет, демо нет. Но... Что менять? поменять стили при помощи js. В цикле, чтобы правый блок(элемент) отображался чуть правее и ниже левого, и более прозрачный(или затемненный бы) По сути, ничего трудного. Попробуйте разобраться исходя из **В третьих**. У самого сейчас задача не решенная второй день, так можно было бы написать костыль какой-нибудь. Можете подождать готовое решение, но, не факт, что оно будет, и если будет, то неизвестно как скоро. Пробуйте сами, вроде направление дал. Либо ожидайте более развернутого ответа или же готового решения. УДачи)

Comment: Корректировка. Глянул на макет. По стилям у правого блока -  падинги сделать, либо уменьшить размер череть width / height. И opacity. **не забудьте**, что когда блок в центре, стили должны быть другие, по этому прогонять это дело через цикл (ну, я так вижу) Либо функцию с применением стилей вызывать в цикле